# Hiding database password in an ms access query

Tags: sql, ms-access, passwords

I need to have a ms-access query which populates data from another access database which is having a password. Below is the sample query I use for this purpose.

```
SELECT field1, field2 
FROM Table1 IN '' [MS Access;PWD=mySecretPassword;DATABASE=C:\db\database1.accdb];
```

I dont want to reveal the database password to any user who opens the this query.
Is there any solution to it?

Comment: Firs thought is to encryt that password.

Comment: care to detail how we encrypt/decrypt a password inside a sql statement ?  I know how to base64 encrypt from powershell, but I'm not sure how to do that inside MS Access.

Comment: First I was thinking I could use a vba function which supplies the password to the query, something like PWD=GetPassword().. But query is not bothering about vba function within 'IN' clause

Comment: It is possible to use ADO and a form with a recordset ( http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281998 ). You could then compile your code.

Comment: Remou: The above query is a standard ms-access query (Not sql with ADO and vba) which needs to be exist as a table view from another table, so that I can create relationships with table in this database and create further queries.